# RStudio v0.97 on Windows 7 64bit -- color2D.matplot will not knit to html, using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to generate the following plot as an html document, using Rmarkdown, in Rstudio:

```
color2D.matplot(M,cs1=c(0,1),cs2=c(0,1),cs3=c(0,1),
                extremes=c(1,3),cellcolors=NA,show.legend=TRUE,nslices=10,xlab="Base Price (R)",
                ylab="GP (%)",do.hex=FALSE,axes=FALSE,show.values=FALSE,vcol=NA,vcex=1,
                border="black",na.color=NA,xrange=NULL,color.spec="rgb",yrev=TRUE,
                xat=NULL,yat=NULL,Hinton=FALSE)
```

But I get the following error:

```
## Error: could not find function "color2D.matplot"
```

However, the plot generates perfectly in the Rstudio 'Plots' display. Is there something that can be done so that Rmarkdown *can* find the function and display the output? Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `M` so we can reproduce this? A nice way would be to run `dput(M)`.

Comment: I think you need just to add  `require(plotrix)` in the chunk.

Answer (score 1):

Use `library(plotrix)` before you call its function `color2D.matplot()`.